# Make raw /_data file viewable on site

Tags: jekyll

Let's say I've got a file in `/_data` called `file.json`, is there an easy way to make that raw file accessible on my site, eg. at `www.mysite.com/file.json`? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to use that data file to populate some data in that site as well, or only serve it as-is?

Comment: @juzraai This looks perfect, thank you!